# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS" Error Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I just upgraded rails to 4.1 and am getting this error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  * AS count_column F...
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  * AS count_column FROM (SELECT thread_id,     max(id) as id FROM "messages"  WHERE 1=0 AND (thread_id IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY thread_id) last JOIN messages ON messages.id = last.id LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

Here is the method:

```
- as_myself do
    %li#messages-open.icon-btn.email
      - message_count = inbox_messages.count.is_a?(Hash) ? inbox_messages.count.values.first : inbox_messages.count
      - if(message_count.present? && message_count > 0)
        %span= message_count
```

Comment: `SELECT * AS count_column` is not a valid sql syntax. It should be something like `SELECT <column_name> AS count_column`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

New syntax in rails 4.1 is `count(:all)` fixed my problem.